# Equation of Lines of Force in Electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

The below given text was given by my professor, I am not able to quite get an intuitive understanding of what's happening here. I am aware of vector functions, space curves and how to find their tangents. But I don't get the choice of the vector over here and how it would seemingly relate to the electric field.

If there is a curve in space, $\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{s})$, whose tangent vector, $\hat{\mathbf{t}}(\mathbf{r})$ at every point lies parallel to the electric field at that point, we have what is referred to as a line of force (or electric field line). If displacements $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r}$ locate two points on the curve and $\Delta \mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}$, then the necessary condition for the curve to represent a line of force is that, as $r_1$ approaches $r$,
$$
\lim _{\Delta \mathbf{r} \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta \mathbf{r}}{\Delta s}=\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{d s} \equiv \hat{\mathbf{t}}(\mathbf{r})=\alpha \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})
$$
where $\alpha$ is a scalar constant and $s$ is taken to measure distance along the curve from some arbitrary point on the curve. If $\mathbf{r}=x \hat{x}+y \hat{y}+z \hat{z}$, then
$$
\begin{gathered}
\frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{d x}{d s}=E_x, \quad \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{d y}{d s}=E_y, \quad \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{d z}{d s}=E_z \\
\frac{d x}{d E_x}=\frac{d y}{d E_y}=\frac{d z}{d E_z}
\end{gathered}
$$

The same concept was also used in a problem discussed during class.

[image]

Comment: I am having a problem understanding what you are asking. You can do the math.  You have a conceptual problem. But I am not sure what that problem is. Is it why the derivative of the curve is proportional to E?

Comment: this equation is wrong: $\frac{d x}{d E_x}=\frac{d y}{d E_y}=\frac{d z}{d E_z}$. Instead it should be $\frac{d x}{E_x}=\frac{d y}{E_y}=\frac{d z}{E_z}$. This is crucial because it makes the E-field integrable that is $\mathbf E = \nabla \phi$ for some $\phi(\mathbf r)$ scalar field. Also, you should have a clearly phrased question, I do not know what you are asking either.